# End interval when route changes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I start a timer in an Angular 2 component which is inside a router outlet.

```
setInterval(() => {
    ...
}, 10000);
```

When I leave the route in which the component is embedded the timer isn't quit. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
routerOnActivate() {
  this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
                ...
            }, 10000);
}

routerOnDeactivate() {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You could clear the interval from this hook.
Mine is controlled from the component/view.

```
export classTestInterval implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
     public timerInterval:any;
     ngOnInit(){
       // Need interval scope in the component could be from somewhere else, but we need scope to be able to clear it on destruction of component.
       this.timerInterval = setInterval(function(){...},10000);
     }
     ngOnDestroy() {
        // Will clear when component is destroyed e.g. route is navigated away from.
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe for what you want is better `OnDeactivate` from `angular2/router` (and maybe also `OnActivate` depending on your usecase) because you said you want to end the timer when the user leaves the route If I understand it correctly.

```
export Compnent implements OnInit, OnDeactivate {
    private timer;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.timer = setInterval(_ => {
            // disco
        }, 10000);
    }

    routerOnDeactivate() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
}
```