# Angular5- setInterval whiten the page

Tags: angular5, setinterval

I am adding notification to my project. The website should shown a number of notification numbers that the user have got without refreshing page. To do so i have used `setInterval` function inside `ngOnInit` but when i used it inside `ngOnInit` the page goes white and shows nothing but the timer is still running.
Here is how i have implement the code.
**ngOnInit**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loginInfoService.getLoginChangeEmitter()
      .subscribe(item => this.loginSuccess(item));

    this.subscription = this.loginInfoService.getSiteNameEmitter()
      .subscribe(item => this.getSiteName(item));

    this.subscription = this.loginInfoService.getSiteDescriptionEmitter()
      .subscribe(item => this.getSiteDescription(item));

    if (innerWidth < 766) {
      this.notificationBell = true;
    } else {
      this.notificationBell = false;
    }

    //if i add this line page goes white
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getAllNotification();
    }, 3000);

  }
```

**Code to get all notification**

```
getAllNotification() {

        this.unSeenNotification = [];
        this.notificationService.getAllNotifications().subscribe(
          result => {
            this.notificationModel = result;
            this.showLoading = false;

            result.forEach(result => {
              if (!result.isSeen) {
                this.unSeenNotification.push(result);
              }
            })

            this.notificationCount = this.unSeenNotification.length;

          },
          error => {
            this.alertService.error(error, "Error!");
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can below window interval:**

```
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {

static intervalId: Number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startInterval();
}

startInterval() void {
    if(FoobarComponent.intervalId) { // always undefined 
        window.clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
    FoobarComponent.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => { 
        console.log('Hi'); }, 1000);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Page appears but timer is not running

Comment: remove window.clearInterval(interval); line and increase time interval so you get idea.

Comment: still the same  problem. Again page goes white and timer is running

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561320/end-interval-when-route-changes-in-angular-2/35561450

Comment: sorry to tell you that this even doesn't solve my problem. Again page went white and shown nothing but timer is still running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169311/discussion-between-nishan-and-dgpoo).